# Data set content is not searchable in active workspace

Tags: solr, architecture

Data set content is not searchable in active work space. If search by using data set name i can find the data set. but if we try using the the content present in data set it won't show the data set,
we are currently using 2 tier configuration .can anyone please suggest the solution , thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have just indexed data set name, not content. if you index content you should get results.

Comment: yeah Thanks ,pls go through this ....I have this configs. In TcFtsIndexer_objdata.properties file marked as "indexDatasetFileContent=true" and in teamcenter RAC added 
"AW_Indexable_File_Extensions"and "AW_Indexable_Object_Type" under this value kept as FullText.doc,.docx.,pdf etc this functionality is working properly with 4tier.
But when changing to 2tier mode dataset content is not searchable.